# How to hide webview in Android when onReceivedHttpError is called

Tags: android, android-webview

My current Android application has a compose WebView.

which resembles this:-

```
val webViewClient = remember {
        object : AccompanistWebViewClient() {

            override fun onReceivedError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, error: WebResourceError?) {
                println( "xxooxx onReceivedError() called with: view = $view, request = $request, error = $error")
            }

            override fun onReceivedHttpError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse?) {
                println( "xxooxx onReceivedHttpError() called with: view = $view, request = $request, errorResponse = $errorResponse")
            }

            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?): Boolean {
                var shouldOverrideUrlLoading = false

                request?.let {
                    if (request.isRedirect) {
                        shouldOverrideUrlLoading = true
                        context.startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, request.url))
                    }
                }

                return shouldOverrideUrlLoading
            }
        }
    }

    val webChromeClient = remember { AccompanistWebChromeClient() }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .wrapContentSize()
            .padding(top = 5.dp)
    ) {
        WebView(
            modifier = Modifier
                .height(60.dp)
                .fillMaxWidth(),
            state = webViewState,
            navigator = navigator,
            client = remember { webViewClient },
            chromeClient = webChromeClient,
            onCreated = { webView ->
                with(webView) {
                    settings.run {
                        javaScriptEnabled = true
                        domStorageEnabled = true
                        javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
                        useWideViewPort = true
                        loadWithOverviewMode = true
                        setInitialScale(1)
                        layoutAlgorithm = WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL
                        scrollBarStyle = View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_INSET
                    }
                    setBackgroundColor(0)
                }
            }
        )
    }
```

is there anyway I can "hide" the webview when an error is detected?

currently i am showing the Server Error web page from my backend server.

how can I control the visibility of my web view from the AccompanistWebViewClient?

UPDATE

cannot believe its this easy

```
  override fun onReceivedHttpError(view: WebView?, request: WebResourceRequest?, errorResponse: WebResourceResponse?) {
            println( "xxooxx onReceivedHttpError() called with: view = $view, request = $request, errorResponse = $errorResponse")

            view?.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```

Comment: It is almost that easy. The only thing you might need to consider is, to run updates to the UI only on the UI-Thread ...